# How can the JavaScript trim function be modified if efficiency is an issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using the following trim - but it is causing slow script in IE

```
function trim(s) {
    return s.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
}
```

Comment: This, all by itself, can't cause "slow script" warnings in IE. You'd have to be calling it in a substantial loop. If this operation puts that loop over the limit, you want to look at the loop because it's running very, very close to the edge. Note that "slow script" warnings in IE are not based on time, but on the number of operations you perform without yielding.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function trim(s) {
    s.replace(/^\s*((?:[\S\s]*\S)?)\s*$/, '$1');
}
```

It's the fastest for most strings in both FF and IE: [More info here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript)

If you have access to jQuery you can also use:

```
$.trim(myString);
```

It seems odd that your regex - even being called twice on the same string - would cause a slow script error. Are you positive this is the cause?

Comment: I'm currently trying to work out what the issue is - but I'll test your trim and see if I get an improvement - cheers